# Why do we not have autonomous helicopters?

Tags: aircraft-design, helicopter, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, vtol

We see a lot of fixed wing autonomous UAVs. What is preventing this in the case of helicopters? 
I know the helicopter flight dynamics are complicated. But what exactly is the complication in this case?

Comment: *"We see a lot of fixed wing autonomous UAVs*" - do we? Where? You realise the millitary UAVs that you're perhaps thinking of have 2 flight crew sitting on an unnamed base somewhere half way round the world, right? Furthermore, most *Actual* autonomous UAVs are drones... which are probably closer to helicopters than fixed wing aircraft.

Comment: Yes even they are not autonomous in the true sense of the word. But fixed wing autonomy is possible. The challenges it faces are different and are being worked upon. When it come to helicopters, they are not even as popular as the so called autonomous fixed wing UAVs. Hence the question.

Comment: I have never, not once, ever, _seen_ an _autonomous_ UAV.

Comment: I guess the OP has never seen this thing either: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaman_K-MAX

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_Eagle_Eye https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_A160_Hummingbird https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northrop_Grumman_MQ-8_Fire_Scout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multirotor autonomous craft are making headway.
Here is one named [Vahana](https://www.nbcnews.com/mach/science/watch-airbus-s-new-air-taxi-make-its-maiden-flight-ncna852006) that was in the news recently. The Vahana link has video too.

https://media4.s-nbcnews.com/j/newscms/2018_09/2345131/180228-vahana-air-taxi-main-art-mn-1210_ebe3af14b2fcd27626c26bd127203e22.focal-1000x500.jpg

Here is [another](http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-43386917) being tested in New Zealand 
https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/18433/production/_100397399_mediaitem100397398.jpg

Google "airtaxi" and there are many links to companies like Uber that have plans and visions for autonomous airtaxi service.  Some have scale mockups, some have just pictures.

I haven't seen any plans for autonomous helicopters, only multirotor vehicles. The multirotor vehicles give you a chance at recovery should one motor be lost; a helicopter, not so much.

Answer (score 1):

Don't we? Most consumer and commercial UAV are helicopters.

If you mean military-only models, consider what jobs military-only helos do. It's troop transport or close combat - both necessarily manned functions. Commercial drones suffice for non-military-specific jobs.

If you wonder why they have 4 rotors rather than 1-2, it's lower complexity - quads can use simple fixed rotors and blades, and only vary power on each rotor. Larger drones with turbine power may well go to 1-2 rotors.